# Session Data not Saving Across Requests With Angular 5 Frontend and .Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-cookies

We are trying to set up some simple session data for our .net core api. We have and angular 5 application that is our frontend running on port 4200 and the api is .net core running on port 5000.

Every example I can find online seems to have the same results. That the session data doesn't presist from requests to request. It is as if the api can't figure out that it is the same user making the subsequent requests.

I believe I have configured it correctly in my Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
    // ....
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSessions();
    // ....
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider versionProvider)
{
    // ...
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
    // ...
}
```

Then I try to test the implementation in one of my controllers

```cs
[HttpGet]
public Task<IEnumerable<UserModelV1>> Query([FromQuery] string email, [FromQuery] string instanceId)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "This is a test");
    return _userService.Read(userId, email, instanceId);
}

[HttpPost("delete")]
public IActionResult BatchDelete([FromBody] string[] ids)
{
    var message = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");
    return _userService.Delete(ModelState, userId, ids.ToList());
}
```

Based on everything I read the session data in the `BatchDelete` method should equal "This is a test", but for some reason it is always `null`.

Comment: Sessions use cookies to establish and recognize a session. In a typical SPA you are making stateless API calls though that will not contain cookies. – It's generally discouraged to rely on state/sessions in REST APIs.

Comment: We are trying to check app store receipts so see if a user is a subscriber or not. Rather than checking every request we thought we would check it once, then save wether they were a subscriber in the session. That way we would only need to make that request out to the app store once every 10 minutes or so. Would you say that is a bad practice?

Comment: I would make that information part of the user claims that are included in the authentication token the user will use anyway to authenticate with your API. If you need to verify it more often, just make a look-up on the user identifier and have a cache on your API. No need to involve sessions there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I'll look into that. We (corporate) have our own identity service which I unfortunately don't have access to or much say on new features.